# What is the actual risk when my 6-month old chews on a USB battery pack?

Tags: batteries, safety, short-circuit

I'm asking... err... for a friend, a theoretical friend...

Now, before everyone piles on with "Thats a terrible idea, your child will definitely die", I'm not interested knee-jerk reactions.  I would like to know what is the actual risk - and how can it be mitigated.  For example, there is some chance that the battery will spontaneously combust, but if that chance is more remote than (for example) a baby having a heart attack (1/100000) it's not particularly relevant.

Now, the actual question...

I have created a simple wearable arduino-nano based device to potty-train my 6-month old.  For the device to be really effective it needs to be running 24/7.

The device is powered by a 10000 mhA battery pack and is strapped to his waist.  The drain is miniscule (I badly misjudged requirements there), and he can't get the live ends to his mouth anyway.  However, he has just discovered he can get the other end up, and enjoys chewing it, and babies can make a *lot* of saliva.

So... what are the risks here? (numbers would be *great*).  If the moisture makes its way inside the battery casing, could it cause any sort of chemical leakage?  If the ports get wet, could it short the battery and start a fire?  Am I being paranoid or irresponsible here?

would (for example) hot-glue-gunning the ports be a good idea?  I'd rather not - I've already replaced the cables once and the current one is looking pretty mangled already.

-- EDIT -- Battery in question is this one: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01B5RZOB6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: surely you can opt for a safer battery option?

Comment: Child safety and Battery short circuit protection must be double protected or even triple protection against any accidental leakage, fall, chew etc.  But it sounds like a clever kiwi idea...  Do you trust your battery supplier and your design to be faultless?

Comment: Beads of glue, batteries, potty training a 6 month old? This isn't a knee jerk reaction but a serious response that other stacks like Paerenting use... Don't rely on random strangers on the internet for the safety of your child. Your initial defensiveness and trying to be cute about it "I'm asking... err... for a friend, a theoretical friend" implies to me you know it's dangerous but want some random person to say you're right. Building an electronic toy by hand and supervising playing with it is a great idea. This is a bad idea.

Comment: Bageletas: glue is non-toxic, cables are well wrapped, and the 1000's of lbs of CO2 that diapers cost are long-term costs that you should probably include in your cost/benefit analysis.  I'm not worried about those factors, I'm specifically asking if there is something I've overlooked in the battery department

Comment: I can edit the question to remove the 'cuteness' if you feel that would improve the quality of the answers.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75  errr... maybe?  I hear of battery packs exploding, but given their frequency (1 per million?) and cause (overheating - not likely on a nano) I've discounted it as a real risk

Comment: I might think a 9V battery and a wet diaper sensor with a piezo beep buzzer is all you need.

Comment: LOL - it's a bit more complicated than that...  and wouldn't a 9v battery be a lot more risky than the usb version?

Comment: why is it more complicated?    batteries only explode from internal or external shorts and less likely on 9V so double protection everywhere.

Comment: The device streams to an app, which does the magic.  The USB pack claims short-circuit/overheating protection.  I feel like that would be reliable, as it's fairly straight-forward to implement (yes?)

Answer (score 8):

> If the moisture makes its way inside the battery casing, could it cause any sort of chemical leakage? If the ports get wet, could it short the battery and start a fire? Am I being paranoid or irresponsible here?

Yes and yes and irresponsible.

There are a multitude of special laws for designing toys and items for children. A non - waterproof high capacity lithium cell for a baby is incredibly bad. Hot glue is likely not kid safe either. Cables are choke hazards.

Comment: Oops - I may have downvoted by accident.  No offense though - but this answer isn't particularily useful.  Special laws for children aren't much of a help - nobody is regulating sugar and obesity costs about 1 life in 30.  Also, after thinking about this for a second any USB port is voltage & current regulated so should not short.  I'm unsure that part 2 of your answer is correct

Comment: @FrozenKiwi "should" doesn't include may cheap and knock-off products, and even those protection circuits won't work if they get wet as that's outside their intended use case

Comment: 99% of usb ports are not current regulated. Many are referenced to main voltage too.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the battery could end up leaking or causing a fire, especially if wires  are chewed, frayed, and ultimately shorted. But another problem to consider is wearability. Babies fall down... a lot.

[Battery operated devices for babies](https://www.nurse.com/blog/2012/05/21/batteries-sucking-devices-pose-dangers-to-children-4/)

> In the United States, 45,398 children younger than 3 were treated in the ED for such injuries between 1991 and 2010  about 2,270 children per year. Most injuries (86%) occurred from falls while using the products, with 83% of falls resulting in lacerations or contusions to the mouth and face. The authors also found that two-thirds of injuries occurred among 1-year-olds, an age when children are unsteady on their feet and prone to falls.

This is especially dangerous if fingers could get caught up by the device, tangled in wires, stuck behind the instrument, etc. Falls would lead to broken fingers.